# Generic sorter function C# to VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, sorting, lambda

Anyone want to try converting this to VB?

```
public class GenericSorter<T, PT>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable source, string sortExpression)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

        var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, PT>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortExpression), typeof(PT)), param);

        return source.OfType<T>().AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T, PT>(sortLambda);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> source, string sortExpression)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

        var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, PT>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortExpression), typeof(PT)), param);

        return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T, PT>(sortLambda);
    }
}
```

This is as far as I got...

```
Public Class GenericSorter(Of T, PT)
    Public Function Sort(ByVal source As IEnumerable, ByVal sortExpression As String) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "item")

        Dim sortLambda = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, PT))(Expression.Convert(Expression.[Property](param, sortExpression), GetType(PT)), param)
        Dim s As IEnumerable(Of T) = source.OfType(Of T).AsQueryable().OrderBy(Of T, PT) (Of sortLambda)

        Return s
    End Function
```

It is supposed to sort any type of object. Taken from [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Self_Sorting_GridView_with_LINQ_Expression_Trees.aspx)

Comment: Why convert at all? Just use the assembly you already have as a reference and use the original directly.

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @Oded - If I could give more I would. The whole point of the CLR is that you can write in whichever language you feel like - it all ends up as MSIL anyway!!

Comment: @Duncan. That's what @Oded is saying - you don't need to rewrite as you've already got it coded in CLR.

Comment: @Jon - thats why I upvoted his comment :-)

Comment: It might help me understand it if I can convert it. I'm all for black box solutions when under time pressure but how will I learn anything?

Answer (score 2):

DeveloperFusions's converter ([here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)) returned this:

```
Public Class GenericSorter(Of T, PT)
    Public Function Sort(source As IEnumerable, sortExpression As String) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "item")

        Dim sortLambda = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, PT))(Expression.Convert(Expression.[Property](param, sortExpression), GetType(PT)), param)

        Return source.OfType(Of T)().AsQueryable(Of T)().OrderBy(Of T, PT)(sortLambda)
    End Function

    Public Function Sort(source As IEnumerable(Of T), sortExpression As String) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "item")

        Dim sortLambda = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, PT))(Expression.Convert(Expression.[Property](param, sortExpression), GetType(PT)), param)

        Return source.AsQueryable(Of T)().OrderBy(Of T, PT)(sortLambda)
    End Function
End Class
```

Its probably worth a try.

Comment: I get:
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AsQueryable' accepts this number of type arguments. 
Anyone else get that?

Comment: Also tried converting here: http://converter.telerik.com/ but still get the above error message.

Comment: I have given up trying this generic sorter and done a more specific sort in the end.

Comment: even I am getting this error for Return source.AsQueryable(Of T)()

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle and Dominating. The question doesn't state which .Net version he is working with, but the AsQueryable<T> is from .Net 4 onwards. So using this code in earlier versions won't work for the reason you've stated. The description of AsQueryable<T> is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003.aspx